How to to update events with offline / CAPI and only server-side implementation? Facebook counts twice same conversions even with same event_id
I'm trying to update my Lead Values using the API. I only use server side to send first party data, the thing is that I need to readjust the values of these leads the first days / weeks, and there isn't any mechanism that I see to do so.
The only most logical way would be to send same events with same event_id and Facebook deduplicates or updates the event to the most recent one. But the documentation states the following:
"Does not deduplicate events when only using one event source, that is browser-only or server-only. If you send us two consecutive browser events with the same information, we do not discard either. If you send us two consecutive server events with the same information, we do not discard either."
Would be there any way to delete / update events with more fresh data? Don't want to send my Leads with a lot of delay of the time event.
I'm sending events with the first value I have on my BD, but it is not 100% accurate over time.
